# Charge saved credit card - Connect V2

Tags: square, square-connect

How can I charge customers with saved credit cards?

Card object returns ID, how can I transform that ID to credit card nonce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to.

The Charge endpoint takes either a `card_nonce` or a combination of a `customer_id` and a `customer_card_id`. In that case your json body would look something like this:

```
{
  "idempotency_key": "xxxx",
  "amount_money": {
    "amount": 100,
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  "customer_card_id": "{{customer_card_id}}";
  "reference_id": "some optional reference id",
  "note": "some optional note",
  "customer_id":"{{customer_id}}",
  "delay_capture": false
}
```

You can read more about it with a ruby example on this page: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/processing-recurring-payments-ruby

Comment: Thank you for your help again :)